# Access an application running on in minikube with istio inside an EC2 instance from outside world

Tags: random

I have an EC2 instance say its IP is 13.XX.XX.XX (Say IP1), I have an minikube which is running inside this EC2 instance say its IP is 10.XX.XX.XX (Say IP2) , which I came to know by doing minikube ip inside EC2 instance . I have an application running inside minikube . I am able to curl to application by doing curl http://IP2

I am using simaple istio-sample application for testing I have configured below with details
ubuntu@ip:~/istio-1.18.2$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE      NAME                                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
default        details-v1-698b5d8c98-h5tbb                2/2     Running   0          24m
default        productpage-v1-75875cf969-zv858            2/2     Running   0          24m
default        ratings-v1-5967f59c58-5wwx2                2/2     Running   0          24m
default        reviews-v1-9c6bb6658-tb8rp                 2/2     Running   0          24m
default        reviews-v2-8454bb78d8-rrtl8                2/2     Running   0          24m
default        reviews-v3-6dc9897554-h6h5n                2/2     Running   0          24m
istio-system   istio-egressgateway-57f9b4cdf5-tdbj8       1/1     Running   0          74m
istio-system   istio-ingressgateway-54f4b997fc-grnqz      1/1     Running   0          74m
istio-system   istiod-5489dc5cb7-mk5gd                    1/1     Running   0          75m
kube-system    coredns-64897985d-ffjkq                    1/1     Running   0          76m
kube-system    etcd-ip-172-xx-xx-xxx                      1/1     Running   3          77m
kube-system    kube-apiserver-ip-172-xx-xx-xxx            1/1     Running   3          77m
kube-system    kube-controller-manager-ip-172-xx-xx-xxx   1/1     Running   3          77m
kube-system    kube-proxy-97gr2                           1/1     Running   0          76m
kube-system    kube-scheduler-ip-172-xx-xx-xxx            1/1     Running   3          77m
kube-system    storage-provisioner                        1/1     Running   0          77m
ubuntu@:~/istio-1.18.2$ kubectl get svc --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE      NAME                   TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                                                                      AGE
default        details                ClusterIP      10.106.199.96            9080/TCP                                                                     24m
default        kubernetes             ClusterIP      10.96.0.1                443/TCP                                                                      77m
default        productpage            ClusterIP      10.104.163.184           9080/TCP                                                                     24m
default        ratings                ClusterIP      10.97.82.158             9080/TCP                                                                     24m
default        reviews                ClusterIP      10.105.167.84            9080/TCP                                                                     24m
istio-system   istio-egressgateway    ClusterIP      10.103.41.18             80/TCP,443/TCP                                                               75m
istio-system   istio-ingressgateway   LoadBalancer   10.106.66.152         15021:31706/TCP,80:31892/TCP,443:30491/TCP,31400:30512/TCP,15443:31409/TCP   75m
istio-system   istiod                 ClusterIP      10.96.231.111            15010/TCP,15012/TCP,443/TCP,15014/TCP                                        75m
kube-system    kube-dns               ClusterIP      10.96.0.10               53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP                                                       77m
ubuntu@:~/istio-1.18.2$ kubectl get nodes --all-namespaces
NAME               STATUS   ROLES                  AGE   VERSION
ip-172-xx-xx-xxx   Ready    control-plane,master   77m   v1.23.3

But I want to access this application out side ec2 through any other PC . How to do this , I tried doing http://IP1 but it didnit work

I tried a lot but can't find solution.